# Declare arguments with interface on typescript react hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx, react-tsx

I am trying to create a custom hook that receives 2 typed arguments with an interface but I am getting a message `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2`, I am not sure if I am declaring the interface wrong or if the file can't be tsx

[image]

File `index.tsx`

```
const [thisPage, setThisPage] = useState(1)

const changePage = (newNumber?: number): void => {
  console.log(newNumber ?? thisPage)
}

const { goNext, goBack } = useSideButtons(changePage, setThisPage)
```

File `useSideButtons.tsx`

```
import { useEffect, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface ISideButtons {
  changePage: (newNumber?: number) => void
  setThisPage: (value: SetStateAction<number>) => void
}

interface ISideExports {
  goNext: () => void
  goBack: () => void
}

export default function useSideButtons ({ changePage, setThisPage }: ISideButtons): ISideExports {
  useEffect(changePage, [])

  const goNext = (): void => {
    setThisPage((actual) => {
      const newNumber = actual + 1
      return newNumber
    })
  }

  const goBack = (): void => {
    setThisPage(actual => {
      if (actual > 1) {
        const newNumber = actual - 1
        changePage(newNumber)
        return newNumber
      } else {
        return 1
      }
    })
  }

  return { goNext, goBack }
}
```

I know that using like this works, but I want to declare an interface to make the code easier to read:

```
import { useEffect, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface ISideExports {
  goNext: () => void
  goBack: () => void
}

export default function useSideButtons (
  changePage: (newNumber?: number) => void,
  setThisPage: (value: SetStateAction<number>) => void
): ISideExports {
  useEffect(changePage, [])

  const goNext = (): void => {
    setThisPage((actual) => {
      const newNumber = actual + 1
      localStorage.setItem('instandaThisPage', String(newNumber))
      return newNumber
    })
  }

  const goBack = (): void => {
    setThisPage(actual => {
      if (actual > 1) {
        const newNumber = actual - 1
        changePage(newNumber)
        localStorage.setItem('instandaThisPage', String(newNumber))
        return newNumber
      } else {
        return 1
      }
    })
  }

  return { goNext, goBack }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion is due to the destructuring you are doing here: `function useSideButtons ({ changePage, setThisPage }: ISideButtons)`

This code means there is one parameter, not two. It is similar to writing

```
function useSideButtons (sideButtons: ISideButtons) {
    const changePage = sideButtons.changePage;
    const setThisPage = sideButtons.setThisPage;
    // Rest of your code

}
```

As you can see in the example above, you only have 1 parameter to the function.

So instead of passing two parameters like this: `useSideButtons(changePage, setThisPage)`, you probably intended to pass one object containing both values like this: `useSideButtons({ changePage, setThisPage })`